# Fauna Search By Ref

Tags: faunadb

I have two documents in the `products` collection...

```
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("products"), "300137558676865540"),
  "ts": 1622492331145000,
  "data": {
    "product_id": 1004,
    "display_name": "Product By ABC",
    "description": "Product Description ABC",
    "status": "in_stock",
    "price_current": 100,
    "supplier": Ref(Collection("suppliers"), "300137504766427654")
  }
},
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("products"), "300137592998855170"),
  "ts": 1622492386360000,
  "data": {
    "product_id": 1005,
    "display_name": "Product By XYZ",
    "description": "Product Description XYZ",
    "status": "in_stock",
    "price_current": 150,
    "supplier": Ref(Collection("suppliers"), "300137513423471107")
  }
}
```

then I have also two documents in my `suppliers` collection...

```
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("suppliers"), "300137504766427654"),
  "ts": 1622492279715000,
  "data": {
    "supplier_id": 205,
    "display_name": "Test Supplier ABC"
  }
},
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("suppliers"), "300137513423471107"),
  "ts": 1622492287963000,
  "data": {
    "supplier_id": 206,
    "display_name": "Test Supplier XYZ"
  }
}
```

How do I search the `products` collection by the `supplier` reference field? Any help is appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All searching in Fauna is done using indexes. You need to create an index for your "products" collection, specifying "supplier" as the search field (aka the `terms` field in the index):

```
CreateIndex({
  name: "products_by_supplier",
  source: Collection("products"),
  terms: [{ field: ["data", "supplier"]}]
})
```

Then you can find all products where the `supplier` field matches the reference for a specific supplier:

```
> Paginate(
  Match(
    Index("products_by_supplier"),
    Ref(Collection("suppliers"), "300137504766427654")
  )
)
{ data: [ Ref(Collection("products"), "300137558676865540") ] }
```

If you want to verify that the results are correct, you can iterate over the results to fetch the associated product documents:

```
> Map(
  Paginate(
    Match(
      Index("products_by_supplier"),
      Ref(Collection("suppliers"), "300137504766427654")
    )
  ),
  Lambda("X", Get(Var("X")))
)
{
  data: [
    {
      ref: Ref(Collection("products"), "300137558676865540"),
      ts: 1622501576960000,
      data: {
        product_id: 1004,
        display_name: 'Product By ABC',
        description: 'Product Description ABC',
        status: 'in_stock',
        price_current: 100,
        supplier: Ref(Collection("suppliers"), "300137504766427654")
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that the `ts` field in my result differs from yours, because I just created those documents.

See the search tutorial for more details: https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/indexes/search